# C++ sstream skipping first three inputs from a file

Tags: c++, sstream

I need to open a file in this format

```
Dat Nguyen 77.7 88.8 99.9 11.1 22.2

Pat Nguyen 2 3 4 5 6
```

I need to assign the first name of a line to a member array of structs and last name of the line to another member of the struct and each number of the line to a array of scores in the struct and each new line goes to the next index of the struct array, doing the same thing (Sorry if I worded that badly).

I have the first name and last name assignment going fine but when it gets to assigning the numbers to the struct members, it skips the first three numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
void fileLoad(Gradebook *students, int &stuCount, int &assignments)
{
ifstream fin;
fin.open("Scores.txt");
if (!fin.is_open())
    cout << "Failed to open file.\n";

if (stuCount < 10)
{
    int n = 0;
    string tempLine;
    string line[10];
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, tempLine);
        line[n] = tempLine;
        stringstream ss(tempLine);
        ss >> students[stuCount].fname >> students[stuCount].lname;
        assignments = 0;
        for (int i = 0; tempLine[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            ss >> students[stuCount].score[assignments];
            if (tempLine[i] == ' ')
                assignments++;

        }
        cout << line[n] << endl;
        assignments--;
        stuCount++;
        n++;
        cout << assignments << endl;
    }
}
else
    cout << "Already max students.\n";
}
```

Here is the output

```
Dat Nguyen 77.7 88.8 99.9 11.1 22.2


Pat Nguyen 2 3 4 5 6


1. Add a new student to the class
2. Assign grades for a new assignment
3. List one student, displaying all their grades and their course average
4. List all the scores for a chosen assignment
5. Display all grades currently contained in the gradebook
6. Save the gradebook to file
7. Exit the program
Enter choice: 3

Enter a student #: 1

Dat Nguyen

Assignment 1: 11.1

Assignment 2: 22.2

Assignment 3: -9.25596e+61

Assignment 4: -9.25596e+61

Assignment 5: -9.25596e+61

Assignment 6: -9.25596e+61

Average: -5.28912e+61
```

Comment: Never use [`while (!fin.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @Nathan what to use instead?

Comment: Replace `while (!fin.eof())` with `while (getline(fin, tempLine))` and remove the `getline()` from the loop body.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Trust me. It changed something. You just haven't gotten far enough in debugging to see the problem it cured. Don't undo that fix.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of logic is suspect:

```
for (int i = 0; tempLine[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    ss >> students[stuCount].score[assignments];
    if (tempLine[i] == ' ')
        assignments++;

}
```

this iterates through all of the characters in `tempLine` one by one and tries to read a whole word from `ss`. Think about that for a second: For every character, read a whole word. `ss` contains a copy of `tempLine` but other than that, they are separate entities. Reading `ss` in word sized blocks and `tempLine` in `char` sized blocks,  words will run out long before the loop terminates. and since OP isn't testing the read of words for success, Crom only knows what's happening.

I think you want something more like:

```
while (assignments < MAX_ASSIGMENTS &&
       ss >> students[stuCount].score[assignments])
{ // read all assignments until array full or couldn't read an assignment score 
    assignments++;
}
```

`MAX_ASSIGMENTS` is a placeholder for whatever OP used to size the `score` array.